# understanding pure js Event function

Tags: javascript

I was just going through the source of [pace.js](https://github.com/HubSpot/pace/blob/master/pace.js#L182) and came across the following function , ::

```
Evented.prototype.trigger = function() {
  var args, ctx, event, handler, i, once, _ref, _ref1, _results;
  event = arguments[0], args = 2 <= arguments.length ? __slice.call(arguments, 1) : [];
  if ((_ref = this.bindings) != null ? _ref[event] : void 0) {
    i = 0;
    _results = [];
    while (i < this.bindings[event].length) {
      _ref1 = this.bindings[event][i], handler = _ref1.handler, ctx = _ref1.ctx, once = _ref1.once;
      handler.apply(ctx != null ? ctx : this, args);
      if (once) {
        _results.push(this.bindings[event].splice(i, 1));
      } else {
        _results.push(i++);
      }
    }
    return _results;
  }
};
```

Now understanding plain JS, is  a bit of a challenge to me, but still I went through the independent components and methods used in the function, but I am really not able to figure out what this function is doing in the plugin.

Can somebody explain? If you can give me a genuine but general idea it will be good enough.

Also can this function be used independent of the plugin pace.js? I plugin pace.js seems to be written in pure js.

**EDIT**: It would be really kind if somebody can comment out whats happening on each line, If you use technical terms that's fine. I can later refer to mdn and understand once I know whats vaguely happening on each line. I understand JS method and anything to do with the web API, MDN has great documentation on it, but everywhere I see `event` that's where I get confused.

Comment: What parts of the code are you not understanding?

Comment: @Bergi , every part that has the word `event` . :)

Comment: @Bergi , but I would prefer if every line , excluding the easy ones (variable declarations etc. ) , could be commented :D am I asking for too much ? :D

Comment: Well `event` is the first argument of that `trigger` method and it then does access the `this.bindings[event]` array to do something with the contents. What are you looking at specifically?

Answer (score 1):

The code you're looking at is compiled coffeescript code, looking at the original code makes it easier to understand:

```
  trigger: (event, args...) ->
    if @bindings?[event]
      i = 0
      while i < @bindings[event].length
        {handler, ctx, once} = @bindings[event][i]

        handler.apply(ctx ? @, args)

        if once
          @bindings[event].splice i, 1
        else
          i++
```

Src: https://github.com/HubSpot/pace/blob/20a7a70028f51c5e511bcb98be5e116f577faa9f/pace.coffee#L164

It checks if there is a binding for the given event, then goes through any existing bindings and calls the handlers for that event.